# how to get the unique word in N number of inputs

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a list of user inputs (N)

```
AGREATBOY
AGREATGIRL
AGREATCITY
```

I need to get the unique word in all user inputs, and want to show answer as GREAT.

How I can do this C++?

Comment: are there spaces in this input? If not, how are you supposed to fine "great" in there? How would you know "great" is a full work, and not some smaller word, like "at"?

Comment: A common word or a longest common substring? A longest substring is AGREAT. On the other hand, finding a longest common word should begin with doing a [segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Text_segmentation&oldid=455995052) of input strings into words.

Comment: No spaces in inputs, need to get the common characters in the given sentence

Comment: Given that someone was able to answer this years ago, I think it's clear enough to be a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Longest_common_substring_problem&oldid=465170006). Consider looking at [implementations for two strings at Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring&oldid=2214955). There's also a [similar question regarding longest common subsequence in multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752208/longest-common-subsequence-for-multiple-sequences). It might help tackling this problem as well.