# Longest Common Subsequence of Three Sequences of int

Tags: c++, dynamic, lcs, subsequence

I am tring to solve the Longest Common Subsequence of Three Sequences of int using C++. the problem is a classic:

> **Task**. Given three sequences A = (a1, a2, . . . , an), B = (b1, b2, . . . , bm), and C = (c1, c2, . . . , cl), find the length of their
>   longest common subsequence, i.e., the largest non-negative integer p
>   such that there exist indices 1 ≤ i1 < i2 < · · · < ip ≤ n, 1 ≤ j1 <
>   j2 < · · · < jp ≤ m, 1 ≤ k1 < k2 < · · · < kp ≤ l such that ai1 = bj1
>   = ck1 , . . . , aip = bjp = ckp
>
> **Input Format**. First line: n. Second line: a1, a2, . . . , an. Third line: m. Fourth line: b1, b2, . . . , bm. Fifth line: l. Sixth
>   line: c1, c2, . . . , cl .
>
> **Constraints**. 1 ≤ n, m, l ≤ 100; −109 < ai , bi , ci < 109 .
>
> **Output Format**. Output p.

My solution was OK for 28 over 29 cases, however, I can't find the error

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
using std::vector;

int get_position(int alpha,vector<pair<int,int>> vect, int A,int B ) {
    if (alpha == 8) {
        int gamma = 0;
    }
    if (A != B) {
        if (vect[A].first == alpha) {
            return vect[A].second;
        }
        if (vect[B].first == alpha) {
            int petitb = B;
            while ((petitb > A) && (vect[petitb].first == alpha))
                petitb--;
            if (vect[petitb].first == alpha) return vect[petitb].second;
            else {
                petitb++;
                if (vect[petitb].first == alpha) return vect[petitb].second;
            }

            return vect[B].second;
        }
        int mid = (A + B) / 2;
        if (vect[mid].first == alpha) {
            return vect[mid].second;
        }
        if (vect[mid].first > alpha) {
            if (mid == B) return -1;
            return get_position(alpha, vect, A, mid);
        }
        else {
            if (mid == A) return -1;
            return get_position(alpha, vect, mid, B);
        }

    }
    else {
        if (vect[A].first == alpha) {
            return vect[A].second;
        }

    }
    return -1;
}
int get_relative_pos(int alpha, vector<pair<int, int>> vect,vector<int> V, int A, int B) {

    int absolute = get_position(alpha, vect, 0, vect.size()-1);
    if ((absolute >= A) && (absolute <= B)) {
        return absolute;
    }
    if (absolute > B)
    return -1;
    if (absolute < A) {
        if (V[A] == alpha) { return A; }
        else { return -1; }
    }
    return -1;
}
bool comp1(pair<int, int>A, pair<int, int>B) {
    if (A.first == B.first)
        return A.second < B.second;
    return A.first < B.first;
}
int explore(vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b, vector<int> &c, int PA, int PB, int PC) {
    int length = 0;
    while ((PA<a.size()) && (PB<b.size()) && (PC<c.size())) {
        if ((a[PA] == b[PB]) && (a[PA] == c[PC])) {
            length++;
            PA++;
            PB++;
            PC++;
        }
        else {
            return length; 


        }

    }
    return length;
}
int explore2(vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b, vector<int> &c, int PA, int PB, int PC, vector<pair<int, int>> SA, vector<pair<int, int>> SB, vector<pair<int, int>> SC) {
    int length = 0;
    while ((PA < a.size()) && (PB < b.size()) && (PC < c.size())) {
        if ((a[PA] == b[PB]) && (a[PA] == c[PC])) {
            length++;
            PA++;
            PB++;
            PC++;
        }
        else {
            //return length;
            int Bprim = get_relative_pos(a[PA], SB,b, PB, SB.size() - 1);//get_position(a[PA], SB, PB, SB.size() - 1);
            int Cprim = get_relative_pos(a[PA], SC,c, PC, SC.size() - 1);//get_position(a[PA], SC, PC, SC.size() - 1);
            if ((Bprim != (-1)) && (Cprim != (-1))) {
                PB = Bprim;
                PC = Cprim;
            }
            else { PA++; }
        }

    }
    return length;
}
int cleanData(vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b, vector<int> &c, vector<pair<int, int>> SA, vector<pair<int, int>> SB, vector<pair<int, int>> SC) 
{
    int indexA, indexB, indexC;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        indexB = get_position(a[i],SB,0,SB.size()-1);
        indexC = get_position(a[i], SC, 0, SC.size() - 1);
        if ((indexB == (-1)) || (indexC == (-1)))
            a.erase(a.begin()+i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
        indexA = get_position(b[i], SA, 0, SA.size() - 1);
        indexC = get_position(b[i], SC, 0, SC.size() - 1);
        if ((indexA == (-1)) || (indexC == (-1)))
            b.erase(b.begin() + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
        indexB = get_position(c[i], SB, 0, SB.size() - 1);
        indexC = get_position(c[i], SC, 0, SC.size() - 1);
        if ((indexB == (-1)) || (indexC == (-1)))
            c.erase(c.begin() + i);
    }
    return 0;
}
int lcs3(vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b, vector<int> &c) {
    vector<pair<int, int>> SA;
    vector<pair<int, int>> SB;
    vector<pair<int, int>> SC;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) SA.push_back(make_pair(a[i],i));
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) SB.push_back(make_pair(b[i], i));
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) SC.push_back(make_pair(c[i], i));
    sort(SA.begin(),SA.end());
    sort(SB.begin(), SB.end());
    sort(SC.begin(), SC.end());
    /*cleanData(a,b,c,SA,SB,SC);
    SC.clear();
    SA.clear();
    SB.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) SA.push_back(make_pair(a[i], i));
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) SB.push_back(make_pair(b[i], i));
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) SC.push_back(make_pair(c[i], i));
    sort(SA.begin(), SA.end());
    sort(SB.begin(), SB.end());
    sort(SC.begin(), SC.end());*/
    //write your code here
    int ptrA, ptrB, ptrC;
    int currentMax = 0;
    int lcs = 0;
    ptrA = 0;
    ptrB = 0;
    ptrC = 0;
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        val = a[i];
        ptrB = get_position(val,SB,0,SB.size()-1);
        ptrC = get_position(val, SC, 0, SC.size() - 1);
        if ((ptrB != (-1)) && (ptrC!=(-1))) {
            //currentMax = explore(a, b, c, i, ptrB, ptrC);
            currentMax = explore2(a, b, c, i, ptrB, ptrC, SA, SB, SC);
            lcs = max(lcs, currentMax);
        }
        if ((a.size() - i) < lcs)return lcs;
    }
    return lcs;
}

int main() {
    size_t an;
    std::cin >> an;
    vector<int> a(an);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < an; i++) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    size_t bn;
    std::cin >> bn;
    vector<int> b(bn);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bn; i++) {
        std::cin >> b[i];
    }
    size_t cn;
    std::cin >> cn;
    vector<int> c(cn);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cn; i++) {
        std::cin >> c[i];
    }
    std::cout << lcs3(a, b, c) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Longest Common Subsequence for Multiple Sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752208/longest-common-subsequence-for-multiple-sequences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks really complicated for such problem, I'm guessing that issue isn't just an implementation but the whole idea for solving this.

LCS of three sequences problem is similar to LCS of two sequences. In both cases we use dynamic programming approach. 
For two sequences we have:

```
for i in 1 .. A.size()
    for j in 1 .. B.size()
        if A[i] = B[j]
            lcs_len[i, j] = lcs_len[i - 1, j - 1] + 1
        else
            lcs_len[i, j] = max(lcs_len[i, j - 1], lcs_len[i - 1, j])
```

Later, if you want to get lcs (not just its length), you simply need to backtracing starting from position `(A.size(), B.size())`, and going towards previous values. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem?oldformat=true).

Now for three sequences problem, you just need to add one more loop and if statement, you should be able to come up with this! If not, here is a [spoiler](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lcs-longest-common-subsequence-three-strings/).